# Se duplica Arraylist cuando lo lleno en ciclo for recorriendo un cursor

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, cursor

Buenos dias (Problema)

Ejecuto el ciclo que se ve en la imagen, recorriendo el cursor en el for para extraer los datos y poderlos agregar a un ArrayList, efectivamente los agrega pero cuando recorro el siguiente ciclo del mismo for, se duplica los datos en el arraylist de objetos y aparece lo mismo, como hago para que los guarde efectivamente sin duplicarse.

1 Imagen: Dato no duplicador for=1

2 Imagen: Datos duplicado for=2

3: Imagen: Clase objeto de Arraylist Lugares

Alguna sugerencia?

[image: Imagen sin duplicar datos]

[image: Imagen con reccorido for, duplicando datos]

[image: Clase objeto lugares]

Aqui se resuleve instanciando nuevamente

```html
        for(fila.moveToFirst(); !fila.isAfterLast(); fila.moveToNext()){
            lugares elementos = new lugares();  //Se instancia nuevamente en cada ciclo
            String name = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("Nombre"));
            String marc = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("Marca"));
            String dir = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("Direccion"));
            String Long = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("Longuitud"));
            String Lat = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("Latitud"));
            String numIsla = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("Num_Isla"));
            String TP = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("Tipo_Combustible"));
            String price = fila.getString(fila.getColumnIndex("Precio"));
            elementos.setNombree(name);
            elementos.setMarca(marc);
            elementos.setDireccion(dir);
            elementos.setLonguitud(Long);
            elementos.setLatitud(Lat);
            elementos.setNumero_Isla(numIsla);
            elementos.setTipo_Combustible(TP);
            elementos.setPrecio(price);
            listt.add(elementos);
            //reset();
        }
```

Comment: Aparte de la cuestión de que la pregunta es un duplicado, el código debería presentarse como texto, no como capturas de pantalla. Y estaría bien expresar mejor el problema (la primera lectura de tu texto me dice que se están creando dos *ArrayList*, cuando lo que pasa es que todos los elementos del único *ArrayList* son iguales). Por favor revisa [help] y [ask].

Comment: Si, me funciono, Tengo que instanciar cada vez que se ejecute el ciclo, Gracias